# Leaflet map markers do not respond on hover or click

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.draw

**AngularJS version 1.5.9
Leaflet version 1.6**

Added Following code to add a map :

```
var imageUrl = "someimageUrl";
                var imageBounds = [[3370, 0], [0, 2384]];


                overlay = L.imageOverlay(imageUrl, imageBounds,{interactive:true});
                overlay.addTo(map);
                var marker = L.marker([515.5, 525.1],
                    {clickable:true,
                     riseOnHover:true,
                     riseOffset :50

                }).addTo(map);
                marker.bindPopup("<b>Hello world!</b><br>I am a popup.");
```

but the pointer for click does not comes up although the clickable is there and also i am 
unable to click on it.

I don't know what is wrong.

Answer (score -1):

get rid of the options, just do:

```
var marker = L.marker([515.5, 525.1]).addTo(map);
```

Comment: You might want to elaborate a little more on your answer, as to why would it fix the problem the OP reported.

Comment: @Jay Mate it does not help in any way adding or removing any sort of options does not makes any changes to it.